# Open Website From App And Redirect Back

Tags: swift3, uiwebview

We have an app that requires a user to make a payment. We have a third party provider that handles the payments. On our website, when the user makes a payment they get directed to the payment portal on the third party's website and after payment, they get redirected back to our website.

I have been tasked to implement the same thing in our iOS Swift 3 app. I have an idea of what I want to do but I am not quite sure how to do it. I started by thinking that I could open the user's browser with a POST request (I know now that I can't) and then using Universal Linking, grab the redirect with the app once payment is complete.

So since I cannot do POST requests on the user's browser, I thought I would implement a UIWebView in my app. Basically I have the code to do this. My question is. How do I capture the redirect from the UiWebView? As far as I can tell, upon successful payment the UIWebView will stay active and the page will redirect, showing our website inside of our app. This is not what I want.

Can anyone explain a better way of doing this? No Code required, but will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Its possible and many apps are doing the same.
There are various methods to do it but What I am doing, I can share. 
I am opening payment page in webview and after success on payment page. The page is redirecting to Success page with SuccessURL. When SuccessURL/FailedURL(Predefined) started loading, I take user back to native app.

```
    func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {    
    if request.url == "sucessURL" {
   //do whatever you want 
    return false
   }
   if request.url == "failedURL" {
   ////do whatever you want 
    return false
   }
    else {
    return true 
    }
```

}

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks mate!